# create a web role for azure cLoud project

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, cloud, azure-web-roles

I need to create a web role for azure cloud project. The role should expose rest api. and send requests  to other service. I created a project and trying to add a web role. VS2013 proposes 2 options : web role asp.net or wcf. I don`t know what is the best for my needs.
What do you advise and why?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a web role, then use Web API to create your service. It is an easy and lightway framework. WCF is for more data intensive operations, requires more setup and you might find it difficult to make it communicate with other services.

What type of service are you going to communicate with?